# Is it possible to apply css transitions on svg nodes? If yes, how?

Tags: css, svg

Let's say I have a simple circle and I want to scale it using CSS. This interaction would be done by listening to a click event on the circle and somehow adding a CSS class (the end frame animation class) to it.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <circle class='main-circle' cx="100" cy="50" r="40" 
      stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Class name for this element is:

```
circleNode[0].className // SVGAnimatedString {animVal: "main-circle", baseVal: "main-circle"}
```

jQuery attempt here:

http://jsfiddle.net/EHfej/

jQuery will not work in this case (see bug http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10329).
className with plain dom nodes does not work either.

My guess is that even though jQuery does not support class manipulations on SVG, it should still be possible.

Comment: What is your question? How to access a specific SVG element via JavaScript to add a class attribute or how to use CSS for transitions in SVG?

Comment: My question is how to add/remove a class (or more) on a SVG element and if adding a class with css3 transform properties will animate the node or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible, however do note that not all properties apply to svg elements. In particular since you seem to be interested in `transform` you should be aware that this may not yet work in all browsers on svg elements. If the property is listed as [required in SVG 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/styling.html) then there's higher probablity that it works in browsers today.

To set the class in svg content:

```
elm.className.baseVal = "yourclass";
```

or use setAttribute:

```
elm.setAttribute("class", "yourclass");
```

Firefox and Opera also supports HTML5 [classList](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/hidden-gems-of-html5-classlist/) on svg elements:

```
elm.classList.add("yourclass");
```

Some examples can be found [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/css3/transitions/).

Comment: thank you, the animated rectangle example was what I was looking for.